# Controlling the dynamics of nonlinear systems with an unknown steady state

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, nonlinear-control

On the one hand, the question is simple, on the other hand, I need the help of specialists in control theory.

Let's take a simple gradient dynamical system:

$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{df}{dx}$

where $f=e^{-(x-x_*)^2}$ and $x_*$ - constant, that constant defining the position of the maximum.

The transition process in such a system is a transition from state $x(0)$ to state $x_*$.

We assume that we don't know the value $x_*$ in advance, as well as the function $f$ itself. How to make sure that transients in such a system always occur exponentially?

We can do anything: add control signals or add auxiliary variables.

Comment: Define exponentially. Do you want to reach the steady-state faster? is the transient allowed to overshoot? Can we assume $f$ is an exponential equation? The simplest way to increase rising time is to just put a gain in the system: $\frac{dx}{dt} = \alpha\frac{df}{dx}$, since the derivative should be zero if the state has reached the unknown steady state

Comment: @Petrus1904

[https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x'%3DD(exp(-(x-1)^2)%2Cx)%2Cx(0)%3D-1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x'%3DD(exp(-(x-1)^2)%2Cx)%2Cx(0)%3D-1)

Take a look at this example. I want the transition from any initial state to the final state to occur exponentially, i.e.:

$x(t)=(x(0)-x_*) \cdot exp(-t) + x_*$


But keep in mind, $x_*$ it is not known in advance, the gradient system is looking for this point.